# Are there any hosting plans that allow multiple sites to be hosted out of the same account?

Tags: hosting, share, domain

I have a couple of sites which I would like to host out of the same account and each should be accessible by their unique domain name (not out of a sub directory or sub-domain) instead of paying individually for several hosts. Are there any companies out there that allows this (or is this not possible on a technical level?). I am not looking for a dedicated but a shared host.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could buy a reseller account and create sub-accounts for each domain. There is also the possibility of just using a regular shared hosting account with `cPanel` as long as the plan offered by the host supports "add-on" domains, in which case they will all sit in your public_html in their own directory.

Comment: Many hosts will let you share your capacity/transfer among several domains and VirtualHost each in it's own directory as gekkz points out. Just find a hosting provider you like and give them a call (they don't bite, just make the call).

Answer (score 1):

Most web hosting company offer such plan. Having multiple sites sometimes mean you may need more support than usual. I suggest you look for quality support above everything, features and price comes next.

Answer (score 0):

We do exactly that using a shared hosting account at [PerformanceHosting](http://www.performancehosting.net/). We're currently running 6 domains under the one account.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to promote these guys any more since they were bought out and their service went to hell, but I used [www.dotable.com](http://www.dotable.com/) for years and years, and they have [multi-domain accounts](http://dotable.com/multiple-domain/803-dotable-multiple-domain-plans.html) which permit this.